# How can I prevent and reclaim Docker EC2 Disk space on /var/lib/docker/overlay2/hash/merged?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, containers

Immediately after the first deployment only 13% is consumed. However, after few days it has significantly increased.

I am using 4 docker container

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/fksdlk      7.8G  4.3G  3.4G  56% /
overlay         7.8G  4.3G  3.4G  56% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/hash/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/hash/shm
overlay         7.8G  4.3G  3.4G  56% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/hash/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/hash/shm
overlay         7.8G  4.3G  3.4G  56% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/hash/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/hash/shm
overlay         7.8G  4.3G  3.4G  56% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/hash/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/hash/shm
```

i cleaned using docker system prune -a and still it is 56% but when we start new EC2 it's 12%

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/fksdlk 7.8G 882M 6.8G 12% /
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I reclaim this space without restarting the EC2 instance?
2. Why is the disk space being consumed?

Answer (score 0):

The size is increasing probably because your containers are writing a lot to stdout.

You don't need to restart the instance, just removing the container will release the allocated storage. You could also run `docker container prune` after removing the containers, just to be sure you don't have any residual content remaining.

Comment: i cleaned using `docker system prune -a` and still it is 56% but when we start new EC2 it's 12%
```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/fksdlk  7.8G  882M  6.8G  12% /
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 8 GB disk for your docker. Thats not good if you want to run containers that hold JVMs etc. Suggest you change your `data-root` to another greater disk location. You have to set this property in `daemon.json` and then just to `systemctl daemon-reload`. Docker will automatically copy its data to your new location.